# Spring applicationContext.xml: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I use spring in my test to load mock 'categoryDAO' delcared in my testApplicationContext.xml file, but running test raises error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.mockito.org/spring/mockito]
Offending resource: file [/Users/sebastien/dev/categorydao/target/test-classes/testApplicationContext.xml]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
```

Here is the test I run:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:**/testApplicationContext.xml"})
public class CategoryDAORetryTest {

    @Autowired
    CategoryDAO categoryDAO;

    @Test
    public void try_several_times() {
        when(categoryDAO.list(anyInt()))
        .thenThrow(new RuntimeException("Remote Exception 1"))
        .thenThrow(new RuntimeException("Remote Exception 2"))
        .thenReturn(Arrays.asList(new CategoryDTO()));

        assertThat(categoryDAO.list(SITE_EN_TGU_US, 10).size(), equalTo(1));
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableRetry
    public static class SpringConfig {

    }
}
```

Here is some others informations related the dependencies I use:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:mockito="http://www.mockito.org/spring/mockito"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.mockito.org/spring/mockito classpath:META-INF/mockito.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com" />

     <mockito:mock id="categoryDAO" class="com.purch.category.dao.CategoryDAO" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

I have also file mockito.xsd to use mock anotation:

```
.
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
 ...
    │   └── resources
    │       └── hibernate.cfg.xml
    └── test
        ├── java
        │   └── com
        │       ├── purch
        │       │   └── category
        │       │       └── dao
        │       │           ├── CategoryDAORetryTest.java
        └── resources
            ├── META-INF
            │   ├── mockito.xsd
            │   ├── spring.handlers
            │   ├── spring.schemas
            │   └── spring.tooling
            └── testApplicationContext.xml
```

Here is the list of spring libraries I use in my pom.xml with "dep.version.spring" to "4.3.1.RELEASE":

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${dep.version.spring}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${dep.version.spring}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${dep.version.spring}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>${dep.version.spring}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-beanutils-core</artifactId>
    <version>${dep.version.commons.beanutils}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>  
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>  
    <version>${dep.version.hibernate-core}</version>  
</dependency> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>${dep.version.spring}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>       
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.8</version>
</dependency>
```

The file mockito.xsd stored in my project is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.mockito.org/spring/mockito"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    targetNamespace="http://www.mockito.org/spring/mockito"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

   <xsd:import namespace="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd"/>

   <xsd:element name="mock">
      <xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="beans:identifiedType">
               <xsd:attribute name="class" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
               <xsd:attribute name="useStaticMap" type="xsd:boolean" default="false" />
            </xsd:extension>
         </xsd:complexContent>
      </xsd:complexType>
   </xsd:element>

   <xsd:element name="spy">
      <xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:attribute name="beanName" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
      </xsd:complexType>
   </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: The problem lies in your `spring.schemas` and `spring.handler` files.

Comment: The issue is a stupid.... the import  "springockito" was missing in the pom.xml. :(
By the way, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

The import "springockito" was missing in my pom.xml!

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.kubek2k</groupId>
   <artifactId>springockito</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.4</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
```